# Why does the following not work when importing an ES2015 module?

Tags: javascript

Why does the following throw a syntax error when importing an ES2015 module?

```
// foo.js
export const FOOS = {
  A: '/a',
  B: '/b',
};

// bar.js
import { FOOS: { A } } from './foo'; // Syntax Error
```

How can I expose constants from a module such that they are available individually (eg. `import { A } from 'foo'`) and collectively as an iterable (eg. `import * from './foo'`)?

Comment: is ti works when you doing smth like `import FOOS from './foo';` ? and then try to reach `A` or `B`?

Comment: Iterable? Modules have nothing to do with that.

Comment: Ok. Not an iterable but all items collectively.